# grep simply fails when used on a few files

Tags: grep

I've been trying for about the past 30 minutes to get this to work properly. `grep` is not exactly the most difficult thing to use, so I'm somewhat baffled as to why this won't work.

The files I'm trying to use `grep` on are simple XHTML log files. Their names are in the format name@domain.com.html, though I don't think that should matter, and inside is simple XHTML.

I copied one such log file to be `testfile` so you can see the output of some commands and why it's baffling to me:

```
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > whoami
reid
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > type grep
grep is /bin/grep
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > uname -a
Linux reid-pc 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:32:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 10 Julia
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > ls -lh testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 reid reid  63K 2011-01-10 12:45 testfile
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > tail -3 testfile 
</body>
</html>
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > file testfile
testfile: XML document text
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > grep html testfile 
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > grep body testfile 
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > grep "</html>" testfile 
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > grep "</body>" testfile
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > cat testfile | grep html
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > cat testfile | wc -l
231
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > cat testfile | tail -3
</body>
</html>
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > chmod a+rw testfile && ls -lh | grep testfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 reid reid  63K 2011-01-10 12:45 testfile
[~/.chatlogs_windows/dec] > grep html testfile
```

That's what I'm attempting to do. I want to just use `grep -ri query .` in `~/.chatlogs_windows`, which normally works perfectly for me... but for some reason, it completely fails at going through these files.

If it matters, I copied these files off of my Windows 7 partition. But I chown'd them and gave myself all the appropriate permissions, and other programs (like `cat`) seem to read them just fine. I also copied testfile to testfile_unix and converted the line endings and tried that, but it didn't work either.

I'm using zsh, but I tried it on bash and that failed too. Also, grep works normally: I tried it out on my documents folder and it worked flawlessly.

If you need any more information, just let me know. I tried googling around, but I found no reason for grep to simply not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In bash, after you execute one of those failing `grep` calls, show the exit status: `echo $?`  (aside: `ls -Alh | grep testfile ` is more easily written/typed as `ls -lh testfile`)

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me either but just to make sure: did you try: cat testfile | grep "html"?

Comment: It gives "1" back as a result. I didn't even think about that. But according to grep's man page, unless I'm misreading it, 1 is the result when the lines aren't found (no matches).

Comment: @anand.arumug: Yes, I tried that and all sorts of variations. No matter what I do, nothing is ever given back.

Comment: Try creating a new file (touch ~/test.txt) and copy/paste the contents of testfile. And try grepping. See what happens.

Comment: That works... for some reason. But why does grepping the regular files not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grep tool doesn't recognise the UTF-16 file encoding.

Comment: Genius! For anyone else who may have this issue in the future, I used the command `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 testfile > testfile_enc` to convert it and tested from there. It'd be nice if grep would inform you of that, though, instead of silently failing.

Comment: Great! learnt something interesting :) Thanks to @Reid and @RedGrittyBrick.

Comment: Grep and Windows files have stolen a tiny bit more of my soul. Thanks @Reid